# Broken PATH in CentOS 5.x

Tags: centos, users, path

I am having troubles with typing commands within the terminal on some of our CentOS servers.  For example, I have to include the complete and full path to the command (i.e. /sbin/chkconfig vs. chkconfig).  This seems to be happening for a number of the expected locations within the system wide PATH.  Some of the locations affected include:

- /usr/sbin/
- /usr/bin/
- /usr/local/sbin/
- /sbin/

I was curious how I could go about correcting this for all users (globally) on the system? I know that for scripting, I always include the full path, but when I am typing commands on the server for routine maintenance or simple troubleshooting, it would be nice to be able to type the command and have it work like it used to.

Note: I have tried this command in the past and it did not work.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
. $HOME/.bash_profile
echo $PATH
```

Comment: What do you mean by “did not work”? What is the value of `$PATH` shown?

Comment: Which user are you logged-in as? Are you escalating to root or leveraging `su` or `sudo`?

Comment: I am escalating to root.  Not using sudo in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is configured in `/etc/profile`, relevant files in `/etc/profile.d/*`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` for bash shells and similar files for other shells.

It is not clear from your question what the exact sequence is of the commands you executed but if you modified the `PATH` before escalating to root that will not have any effect.

If you escalate to root to execute these commands you need to provide us the `PATH` when you've opened a root shell and the shell the root user is using.